# how to prevent default keyboard from popping up and enable copy paste option?

Tags: android, android-keypad

I have my own custom keyboard in my app . In the editText box i disabled its onTouch() by returning true

```
OnTouchListener otl = new OnTouchListener() {
            @Override
            public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
                switch (event.getAction()) {
                }
                return true;
            }
        };
```

This helps in preventing keyboard to popup.But it also disables the touch event, and i am not getting the option to copy paste default feature of android .This scenario is happening in many app but i am not getting any way to do it. Please help.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of disabling touch, you can `setFocusable` to `false`. This will disable the softkeyboard for popping up.

```
editText.setFocusable(false);    
editText.setFocusableInTouchMode(false);
```

And then in `onTouch`, popup your custom keyboard

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

Actually using the below set of properties in edit text xml and setting text in selectable  as true ,despite of returning false in my onTouch() solved my problem .

```
<EditText
            android:id="@+id/numberEditText"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:clickable="true"
            android:textCursorDrawable="@null"
            android:ems="10"
            android:paddingRight="3dip"
            android:focusable="true"
            android:focusableInTouchMode="true"
            android:gravity="center_vertical|end"
            android:cursorVisible="true"
            android:background="@drawable/edittext_style_dialer"
            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
            android:textColorHint="@color/dialer_text_color"
            android:textSize="@dimen/dialer_text_size" >

            <requestFocus />
        </EditText>
```

In the onCreate(),

```
mNumberInputEditText.setTextIsSelectable(true);
```